# Is there a way to watchdog filesystem in python with sudo access file?

Tags: python, filesystemwatcher, watchdog, file-monitoring

Currently i see we have watchdog library but its allow watchdog on only those file that access within logged in user on linux OS or windows OS.

Is there any way to add watchdog for file that access through sudo?

I did tried with watchdog.observer but its throwing error permission denied.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to skip permissions provided by OS. With your current user you would not (and should not) be able to do such thing. The only way comes in mind to flag the script as Sticky bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Comment: Have you tried granting your application sudo rights? I.e. `sudo python foo.py`. Don't execute code you don't trust like this though

Comment: Thanks Nearoo i tried with sudo python foo.py and its working fine.
Thanks a lot for quick help.

Comment: @nearoo any idea do we have any alternate library which can take as param or provide sudo support?